# Creating a Dummy SQL Table to then insert data into

Tags: sql, temp-tables

I am trying to create a temporary table and then insert a query to replace data in that dummy table.

What I am trying to get for the end dummy table looks like this before I insert the new data:

```
Year    MonthNum  Month Application ResourceClass   UptimePercent

2013    1     Jan   Service1    Enterprise Service  1
2013    2     Feb   Service1    Enterprise Service  1
2013    3     Mar   Service1    Enterprise Service  1
2013    4     Apr   Service1    Enterprise Service  1
2013    5     May   Service1    Enterprise Service  1
2013    6     Jun   Service1    Enterprise Service  1
2013    7     Jul   Service1    Enterprise Service  1
2013    8     Aug   Service1    Enterprise Service  1
2013    9     Sep   Service1    Enterprise Service  1
2013    10    Oct   Service1    Enterprise Service  1
2013    11    Nov   Service1    Enterprise Service  1
2013    12    Dec   Service1    Enterprise Service  1
2013    1     Jan   Service2    Enterprise Service  1
2013    2     Feb   Service2    Enterprise Service  1
2013    3     Mar   Service2    Enterprise Service  1
2013    4     Apr   Service2    Enterprise Service  1
2013    5     May   Service2    Enterprise Service  1
2013    6     Jun   Service2    Enterprise Service  1
2013    7     Jul   Service2    Enterprise Service  1
2013    8     Aug   Service2    Enterprise Service  1
2013    9     Sep   Service2    Enterprise Service  1
2013    10    Oct   Service2    Enterprise Service  1
2013    11    Nov   Service2    Enterprise Service  1
2013    12    Dec   Service2    Enterprise Service  1
2013    1     Jan   Service3    Enterprise Service  1
2013    2     Feb   Service3    Enterprise Service  1
2013    3     Mar   Service3    Enterprise Service  1
2013    4     Apr   Service3    Enterprise Service  1
2013    5     May   Service3    Enterprise Service  1
2013    6     Jun   Service3    Enterprise Service  1
2013    7     Jul   Service3    Enterprise Service  1
2013    8     Aug   Service3    Enterprise Service  1
2013    9     Sep   Service3    Enterprise Service  1
2013    10    Oct   Service3    Enterprise Service  1
2013    11    Nov   Service3    Enterprise Service  1
2013    12    Dec   Service3    Enterprise Service  1
```

Would anybody have a good way to pull in the date portions separate from the Applications, as well as the UptimePercent? I can't for the life of me find a resolution.

Comment: Please explain what “insert a query to replace data” means. Are you trying to insert data into an existing table? Update existing data? here is this data you want to insert or update coming from? What does “to pull in the date portions separate from the Applications” mean?

Answer (score 0):

> Would anybody have a good way to pull in the date portions separate from the Applications, 
>   as well as the UptimePercent?

Yes. You could do this:

```
create newtable like oldtable;
```

The create like will work on MySQL anyway.  Then:

```
insert into newtable (Year, MonthNum, Month, UptimePercent) select 
Year, MonthNum, Month, UptimePercent from oldtable;
```